# Mass Update & Mass Edit button Visualforce Error

Tags: button

One of my users gets this error message, "core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesHandledException: Object type not accessible" when they check off multiple checkboxes on the case list and press the mass update or Mass Edit.  The weird thing is that other users, with the same profile and permission sets, don't receive this error (they can successfully use the buttons)?  Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Do a side by side visual confirmation that the profile, permission sets, AND role assignments are the same. Without more info that is the best advice I can offer.